# Not delete record from database in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

Not delete record from database in cakephp

my query for delete record.

```
public function del_mail($mailid)
    {
        $this->Mymail->deleteAll(array('mailid'=>$mailid));
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Delete Successful', true), 'default');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

Error.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Mymail.id' in 'field list'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT DISTINCT `Mymail`.`id` FROM `babysoft_storel`.`mymails` AS `Mymail` WHERE `mailid` = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Mymail.id' in 'field list'
```

You have an error of mysql query and are you sure you have the 'Mymail.id' in your table field?

According to your comment below Please try this :

```
public function del_mail($mailid)
    {
        $this->Mymail->deleteAll(array('Model.mailid'=>$mailid)); //where Model is your Model you used to retrieving the mailid field.
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Delete Successful', true), 'default');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

Comment: i have mailid field in Mymail table not id field.